# Rails - Multiple Relationship Find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, relationships

For the sake of simplifying my problem, let's say we have three models; `user`, `flight`, and `plane`. I want to show a table to the user of how many times they have flown each plane they've flown.

I am completely stuck as to how to achieve this... the most simple solution I could think of is to loop through the flights like so...

```
flown_planes = {}

@user.flights.each do |f|
  if flown_planes[f.plane.id]
    flown_planes[f.plane.id] += 1
  else
    flown_planes[f.plane.id] = 1
  end
end
```

Can I somehow use `.find` and `.count` to achieve this? I'm sure there is a much cleaner way than above. Please see the relationships below.

---

**Flight**

```
class Flight < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :plane
end
```

**Plane**

```
class Plane < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flights
end
```

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flights
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group_by` to group the flights of the user by the planes!

```
@user.flights.group_by(&:plane_id)
```

That should do it for you,...

// For iteration...

```
@user.flights.group_by(&:plane_id).each do |plane_id, flights|
     plane = Plane.find(plane_id) # gives you the plain object so you can fetch the plane name/identification,... whatever you need
     flights.count # gives you count of flights in the plane
     flights.each do |flight|
          # do anything if you want with each of the flights the user had...
     end
end
```

Comment: Ok thanks - but I need to loop from them, and in the loop I need to have the plane object, and the count of how many times the user flew that plane - how can I do that?

Comment: brilliant - second question you've answered for me today :)